# Bind Dynamic column header and data from dataset to repeater with JqueryDatatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, data-binding, datatable

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <tr class="">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Header1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <th align="left"><%# Container.DataItem %>
                </th>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Item1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td><%# Container.DataItem %>
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        Repeater headerRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("Header1") as Repeater;
        headerRepeater.DataSource = dt.Columns;
        headerRepeater.DataBind();
    }

   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater columnRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("Item1") as Repeater;
        var row = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
        columnRepeater.DataSource = row.Row.ItemArray;
        columnRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

My requirement is add columns dynamically and data belongs to that columns. I googled for that I got a link [Bind Dynamic data and column to repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013041/how-to-dynamically-bind-asp-net-repeater-control-to-datasource)
This is working fine. But I would like to apply Jquery.datatable.js for sorting and pagination features and other features which comes by default with jquery's datatable

how can i do?

Comment: You need to get hold on to the table in javascript using '$('#= Repeater1.ClientId').datatable()' something like this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But When I use the Header and ItemTemplate both are dyanamic means you can see in Header I have used Repeater and for Item I have used another Repeater In Repeater1 . In this case I am getting data but not able to apply JqueryDatatable.js features.