# Adding Header to the repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

How to add header to the `Repeater` control? I want to add the header for each columns mentioned

Below is my repeater control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSingleSapDataInfo" runat="server">                                     
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="widget-box widget-blue">
            <div class="widget-main widget-repeater-horizontal">                                
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSapId" runat="server"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SAP_ID") %>' CssClass="labelbold"></asp:Label>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "STATE") %>' CssClass="labelbold"></asp:Label>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNLat" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NEW_LATITUDE") %>' CssClass="labelbold"></asp:Label>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNLong" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NEW_LONGITUDE") %>' CssClass="labelbold"></asp:Label>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblOLat" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OLD_LATITUDE") %>' CssClass="labelbold"></asp:Label>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblOLong" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OLD_LONGITUDE") %>' CssClass="labelbold"></asp:Label>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right1" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRemarks" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "REMARKS") %>' CssClass="labelbold"></asp:Label>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCreatedBy" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CREATED_BY") %>' CssClass="labelbold"></asp:Label>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCreatedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CREATED_DATE", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>' CssClass="labelbold"></asp:Label>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>                   
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeater and add columns to header and itemtemplate on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748108/repeater-and-add-columns-to-header-and-itemtemplate-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the [ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) so use the [HeaderTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.headertemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) to add a header:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSingleSapDataInfo" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        My header
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="widget-box widget-blue">
            ...
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I have multiple columns, how will I add it in one single header ??

Comment: Same way you add the columns in your ItemTemplate with the divs? Please edit the question to be more specific if you need something else, you only asked how to add a header.

Comment: I know my question is not proper, I want to add the header for each columns mentioned ... **UPDATED the question**

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question use Header Template

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rowRepeater" OnItemDataBound="rowRepeater_ItemBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>                                
        <tr>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="headerRepeater">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <th>
                        <%# Container.DataItem %>
                    </th>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUserName" Text='<%# Eval("Key") %>' /></td>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="columnRepeater">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfRoleIndex" Value='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' />
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbColumnValue" Checked='<%# Container.DataItem %>' OnCheckedChanged="cbColumnValue_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </td>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the reference link
[Repeater and add columns to header and itemtemplate on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748108/repeater-and-add-columns-to-header-and-itemtemplate-on-page-load)

it will help you

Comment: so u mean to say, I should write inside header template everything ??

Comment: no you need to add only header in your header template please see the link and see the correct marked answer